# Not able to start node server when electron start

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to start the node server when the electron starts without using the command node server.js. I tried but it says cannot find server.js. How should go about it? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

Here are my screenshots for the various segments:

The file structure:

[image]

The main.js

[image]

The server.js

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you avoid posting screenshot of your code please ? it is not very accessible for everyone

Comment: You need to replace your `require('server.js')` with `require('../../server.js')`, your node js file is 2 folders out of your electron js file that's why you see `..` twice in the new require

Comment: @CharybdeBE, thanks will take note.